# Is it possible to create a cloud build trigger on a cloud source repository present in another Google Cloud project?

Tags: google-cloud-source-repos

I wanted to know if it is possible to create a Cloud build trigger in one Google Cloud Project on a Cloud Source Repository present in another Google Cloud Project. If yes, then how to do it?